# How to open and update json file with jmeter and then run the batch script

Tags: json, batch-file, groovy, jmeter, jsonslurper

I am using jmeter 5.3 and I got my jmeter test, that uses data from pre-created JSON file. I would like to let jmeter to create this file before every test run.
This includes:

1. open existing JSON file
2. update certain values in this file
3. save and close the file
4. run the batch file
5. run the test

that first 4 steps should be executed just once, even I run test for more users. ( I suppose I could use extra thread for that)

I tried to use this sort of code, but it doesn't work.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper("cfg.json")

def taps_count = jsonSlurper.context.parameters.find { "globals" }
taps.count.value."random_taps" = 100

def period = jsonSlurper.context.parameters.find { "time_window" }
period.value."from" = "2020.12.14 08:40:00"
period.value."to" = "2020.12.14 08:45:00"



"script.bat".execute()
```

Comment: and why do you think that `it doesn't work` ?

Comment: getting: ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, Create taps file
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to process file

Comment: the JsonSlurper constructor does not have input parameters. https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html you have to use something like `new JsonSlurper().parse(new File("cfg.json"))`

Comment: when using this: def jsonSlurper = `new JsonSlurper().parse(new File("C:\directory\cfg.json"))` , then jmeter says: _Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script72.groovy: 3: Missing ')' @ line 3, column 52._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper("cfg.json")
```

to this one:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File("cfg.json"))
```

This is the very first and the most obvious error, if you experience further problems you will need to provide the contents of your `cfg.json` file

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [JsonSlurper documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: as I mentioned in another comment for another answer, when using this solution, then I am getting an Exception: _Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script72.groovy: 3: Missing ')'_

Comment: I have not idea what another comment to another answer you're talking about, my expectation is that you're either not too good at copying and pasting the code or you should be escaping a backslash with another backslash given you provide full path to the file like `c:\\somefolder\\someotherfolder\\cfg.json` or just use forward slashes like `c:/somefolder/cfg/json`

Comment: yes, issue was with slashes, using forward slash helped. Now there is no exception in logs, but actually taps_count and period values are not updated in my json file. Is assigning values as I used it enough?

Comment: No, it's not enough and the answer is in one of the 2 provided links. I'm not going to update anything as it's 3rd question which doesn't have anything in common with previous 2 ones and you're supposed to ask a new one if the current is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to execute bat file

> OS Process Sampler is a sampler that can be used to execute commands on the local machine.
> It should allow execution of any command that can be run from the command line.

Comment: yes, I used OS Process sampler for running the command